# Creating a sorted array from the smallest log n tems in a heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a binary heap, I need to create a sorted array containing the smallest log n items from the heap, in O(log n loglog n).

Of course I tried the naive approach of deleting the minimum log n times, but that takes O(log<sup>2</sup>(n)). I don't know how to improve that.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just run a greedy search of the heap, interpreted as a general binary tree. The heap invariant means that when you know the smallest `k` items of the heap, the `k+1`th-smallest must be one of their children. You can build a second heap of all candidates for the next-smallest item, and that heap will never grow beyond `O(log(n))`, so insertions and deletions take `O(log(log(n))`, and you need `O(log(n))` insertions and deletions in the second heap. This works for finding the smallest `k` items of a heap in `O(k*log(k))` time, regardless of what `k` is.

Here's example code in Python:

```
import heapq

def smallestk(heap, k):
    if not k:
        return
    candidates = [(heap[0], 0)]
    for _ in xrange(k):
        val, index = heapq.heappop(candidates)
        yield val
        for child in (2*index+1, 2*index+2):
            if child < len(heap):
                heapq.heappush(candidates, (heap[child], child))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following "pseudocode", runs in O(mlogn) where m is the number of items in the heap. This number surely influences the running time, but I suppose you only care about the variation versus the number of items you want to store.

```
std::vector<heapItem*> myVect;
for each heap-item* p
{ 
  bool inserted = false;
  for(auto it= myVect.begin(); (it!=myVect.end()) && !inserted; ++it)
  { 
    if(p->itemSize > (*it).itemSize)
    {
      myVect.insert(it, p);
      inserted=true;
    }
  }
  if((myVect.size() < logn) && !inserted)
     myVect.push_back(p);
  else if(myVect.size() > logn)
     myVect.resize(logn);
}
```